# Opening attached PDF in neomutt: No Permission

Tags: permissions, mutt

When I open a PDF in Neomutt (by pressing `v` in the opened email and selecting it) then a temporary file `/tmp/doc.pdf` is created.

When I then try to open another PDF (even after closing the first one), the file still exists which causes the second attempt of opening a PDF to fail.

The error message is

```
p: reguläre Datei '/tmp/doc.pdf' kann nicht angelegt werden: Keine Berechtigung
```

which means something like

```
:p regular file '/tmp/doc.pdf' cannot be created: No Permission
```

When I delete that file manually I can open another PDF.

Would it be possible to make neomutt overwrite that file or use a different file name each time?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the online documentation on [configuration](https://neomutt.org/guide/configuration.html) and [MIME types](https://neomutt.org/guide/mimesupport) (search for "pdf")?

Comment: can you provide content of your mailcap file?

Comment: Thanks! That already solved the problem. It stated in the mailcap that it would always write PDFs to `/tmp/doc.pdf` so I changed it so it would just use the original name.